# Mocha + Koa - How to mock KoaContext?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, koa

I am using mocha/chai as a JS testing library for some node code. I am trying to write unit tests for a helper function that accepts a KoaContext.

The function signature looks like this:

```
export const q2m = (ctx: KoaContext, opts: Q2mOptions = {})
```

My Mocha test looks like this:

```
it('should handle an empty query string', function () {
    const ctx: KoaContext = {};

    const result = q2m(ctx, {});

    const expectation: Q2mMongoQuery = {
      rawQuery: ctx.request.query,
      filters: {},
      page: 1,
      limit: 25,
      skip: 0,
      search: null,
      sortField: null,
      sortDirection: 'ASC',
    };

    assert.deepEqual(result, expectation);
  });
```

However, typescript complains that ctx does not have all the defined properties of KoaContext. There are nearly 50+ and I dont think it makes sense to define all of those. Is there a way to mock the context so I can unit test my methods?

Comment: The simple solution would be to use `as any`

Comment: Ya I was thinking that too. Part of me wants to keep it typed as that enforces it in our codebase. For now, Im using ts-ignore in the test. Im not sure which I like best.

E.g.
  const ctx: KoaContext = {
        //@ts-ignore
        request: { query: {} },
      };

Comment: Normally I'm against lying to typescript, but I've made some exceptions in tests because of diminishing returns. Have you looked at mocking tools like Sinon?

Comment: Totally get the view here. I have looked into Sinon. I do plan to use it, but for this particular unit test I thought it was simple enough to just use the KoaContext type. Apparently not! Haha.

Does sinon allow you to partially mock an object? e.g. mock KoaContext to only have the request.query defined?